# determining the seasonal turnover based on months

Tags: sql-server

I have to determine the total turnover per season. For doing this, I have to combine different dates (months), but the problem is that my code gives the months separately and indicate behind each month to which season it belongs and what the turnover per month is. This goes for each year, since my database has dates (months) of different years. I am not interested in the years but in the seasons. Hence, I want to calculate the total turnover per season (over all the years) without seeing the months as result. How can I do this and what do I do wrong in my code?

```
SELECT
    MONTH(H.Startdate) AS Month
    , SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY, H.Startdate, H.Enddate) + 1) * F.DayPrice) + SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY, H.Startdate, H.Enddate) + 1) * A.DayPrice) + SUM(CostReparation) AS TotalTurnover
    , (CASE
           WHEN MONTH(H.Startdate) IN (12, 1, 2) THEN 'Winter'
           WHEN MONTH(H.Startdate) IN (3, 4, 5) THEN 'Spring'
           WHEN MONTH(H.Startdate) IN (6, 7, 8) THEN 'Summer'
           WHEN MONTH(H.Startdate) IN (9, 10, 11) THEN 'Fall'
       END
      )  AS Seasons
FROM
    RentContract                 AS H
    INNER JOIN RentedCar         AS VF
        ON H.RentContractNr = VF.RentContractNr
    INNER JOIN Car               AS F
        ON VF.FrameNr = F.FrameNr
    INNER JOIN RentedAccessories AS VA
        ON H.RentContractNr = VA.RentContractNr
    INNER JOIN Accessories       AS A
        ON VA.Barcode = A.Barcode
    INNER JOIN Damage            AS S
        ON H.RentContractNr = S.RentContractNr
WHERE
    Status = 'Paid'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(H.Enddate)
    , MONTH(H.Startdate)

-- HAVING    MONTH (H.Startdate) IN (12, 1, 2)

ORDER BY
    MONTH(H.Startdate) ASC OFFSET 0 ROW

GO
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: `GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN MONTH(H.Startdate).......`